# bash doesn't execute commands after for loop

Tags: bash, user-input, stdin

I wrote a small installation script for my utilities set:

```
#!/bin/bash

set=(move-volume move-db dmove-copy-id dmove-config dmove-nginx-proxy)

for item in ${set[*]}
do
    wget -q -nv https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pavelsr/dmove/master/$item -O /usr/local/bin/$item
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/$item
done

dmove-config
dmove-copy-id
echo "Setup complete! Do not forget to dmove-copy-id if you updated config"
```

Running installation script like:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pavelsr/dmove/master/install-dmove | sudo bash
```

But it just download files and doesn't execute code after `done`.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin` in your `PATH` environment variable? To check, run `export | grep PATH`.

Comment: Run with `bash -x` to get a trace of the shell expansions and see how far it got.

Comment: @chuckx, yes, it is `root@docker-2gb-blr1-01:~# export | grep PATH
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"`

Comment: @cdarke, seems like code is executed since I see `+ dmove-config` after running `bash -x`. Is it a problem with user input ? My `dmove-config` [contains](https://github.com/pavelsr/dmove/blob/master/dmove-config) `read -p`

Comment: OK, so it *is* executing beyond the loop.  Yes, `read -p` could be an issue, do you get the prompt?

Comment: @cdarke, no, I haven't got the prompt

Comment: OK, I would try entering the data for the `read` on the terminal when it appears to hang.  Also, check that `dmove-config` is running correctly, again you can use the `bash -x` to run it.

Comment: `echo -e "login@ip.addr\nfolder" | dmove-config`

Comment: Not sure if `set` is a good variable name to use...

Comment: @cdarke, `dmove-config` is running fine, `bash -x dmove-config` too.

Comment: It would be so much simpler to just bake all the commands into a single script, instead of having a script which downloads other scripts.

Comment: @Cyrus, but I need an interactive promt during installation

Comment: @Cyrus, sure I can pass parameters directly to STDIN of `dmove-config` but it's not that expected. Since I decided to distribute my script among other users it's better to have interactive promt

Comment: Wrap the entire script in a `{ ...; }` block to ensure its not executed until it's completely downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
dmove-config
```

with

```
dmove-config </dev/tty
```

to force dmove-config reading from tty and not waiting for data from your curl command.